# Return variable with a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Lets say, I have a function:

```
function my_function(some_variable, count, callback) {
    // some code here, doing jQuery animation, transition, etc., f.e:

    var temp = $('#some_element').clone().appendTo('body');

    temp.animate({'top': newOffset.top, 'left': newOffset.left }, 'slow', function() {
        if (callback !== undefined) {
            callback();

            return count;
        }
        else {
            return count;
        }
    });
}
```

So when I call it f.e like this:

```
my_function('test', 75, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

I need to have in the console `75`. But it is returning `undefined`.

So my question is, how I can return in callback the same value, as I passed in the `count`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass variable `count` as parameter to `callback` function

```
temp.animate({'top': newOffset.top, 'left': newOffset.left }, 'slow', function() {
    if (callback !== undefined) {
        callback(count); //Pass whatever value you want to callback method
    }        
});
```

Comment: It's duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call and should have been closed

Comment: @Tushar, I disagree, as OP is already using `callback()` function, his problem is he is not able to pass `count`. Not how to use `callback` method.

Comment: @Satpal But the answers on the question actually answers this question indirectly